# Print message if a certain condition meet on a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataset containing 4 columns and 1  want to apply a condition on 4 columns in on line like
*****IF df.ColumnA > 120 and df,columnB <130 and df.column 4 >80*****  and print message if condition meet .
But when i do this its not working.

Please tell how can I read columns from a file and apply condition on it .

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Book1.csv",
                 names=[ 'SBP', 'DBP', 'HEARTRATE' ])
Time_sensitive_df = (df [ (df [ 'SBP' ] > 110) & (df [ 'DBP' ] > 80) & (df [ 'HEARTRATE' ] < 100) ])
print('\n Time Sensitive Data :\n', Time_sensitive_df)
```

I want to do this in a if else condition.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post your current progress by showing some code you have currently done?. Also please look on the guidelines for asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: mport numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import datetime
import random

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Book1.csv",
                 names=[ 'SBP', 'DBP', 'HEARTRATE' ])                                   
 Time_sensitive_df = (df [ (df [ 'SBP' ] > 110) & (df [ 'DBP' ] > 80) & (df [ 'HEARTRATE' ] < 100) ])
normal_df = (df [ (df.SBP > 120) & (df.DBP > 90) & (df.HEARTRATE < 100) ])
print('\n Time Sensitive Data :\n', Time_sensitive_df)
print('\n Normal Data :\n', normal_df)

Comment: Always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71103940/edit) the question to add code. It will also require a lot more context that you have currently provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# filter results by showing records that meet condition

# sample df
d = {'SBP': [111, 100], 'DBP': [81, 40], 'HEARTRATE':[1,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

# if an alert is found, prints alert, else normal
if len(df[(df[ 'SBP' ] > 110) & (df[ 'DBP' ] > 80) & (df[ 'HEARTRATE' ] < 100)]) >0:
    print('Alert')
else:
    print('Normal')
```

Comment: yes yes ... Thank you so much..

Comment: it work... thank you.. I am doing thesis and there is a many things i have to do but start was from here...

Comment: God Bless you.. :-)

Comment: Awesome! Could you kindly vote this code as helpful? In addition to your other question, I am not familiar with the term "fog computing", but I currently utilize GCP for cloud computing.

Comment: yes i will but i need 15 reputation to cast a vote once i had i will vote..   Oh ok .. do you know anyone who knows about fog computing..

Comment: i have recorded my vote once i have 15 reputations you will get your vote automatically.

Comment: Hi 
Adam Feliciano Hope you are doing well . i need help again from you do you know about python socket programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see revised code below based off your comment and let me know if this is what you need.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
# sample df
d = {'SBP': [111, 100], 'DBP': [81, 40], 'HEARTRATE':[99,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

# get index position based off column name
SBP = df.columns.get_loc('SBP')
DBP = df.columns.get_loc('DBP')
HEARTRATE = df.columns.get_loc('HEARTRATE')

for x in range(len(df)):
    if (df.iloc[x,SBP] > 100) & (df.iloc[x,DBP] > 80) & (df.iloc[x,HEARTRATE] < 100):
        print('Alert')
    else:
        print('Normal')
```

Comment: yes .. But it is printing massage for all values where it is reaching the limit .I want only one alert message or one normal message.   Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Normal
Alert   its output is looking like this ..

Comment: HI do you know about fog computing and cloud computing??

Comment: Hello again, see my new response and let me know if this is what you're looking for. This method simply checks to see if a record meets the condition, if so, it prints "Alert". If no record meets the condition, it prints, "Normal"

Comment: it work... thank you.. I am doing thesis and there is a many things i have to do but start was from here...  do you know about fog computing?